# Should I put "\" or "{}" at the end of commands?

Tags: spacing, typography

I have a discussion with a collegue if one should write `\LaTeX\ format` or `\LaTeX{} format`. After comparing the output, I find that the spacing in the second version is slightly wider than in the first.

This is an 8x enlarged screenshot of the output.

`\LaTeX\ format`:
[image]

`\LaTeX{} format`:
[image]

The latter one has a wider space, which is still visible, even though the images are displayed to have the same width.

Is there something else going on when I use `{}`? What is the proper way to end a LaTeX command?

Comment: Normally it shouldn't matter, but perhaps you redefine `\ `.  Show a small but complete example of your code.

Comment: It seems that the font is smaller in the second case, making the words shorter, so the elastic space between the words has to stretch a bit more. This may be unrelated to `\ ` vs. `{} `. As Ulrike suggests: please post the LaTeX code of a small document that produces this output.

Comment: @gernot: the font only seems smaller, since the pic is a bit wider.

Answer (score 8):

There should be no difference between using `\LaTeX{}` or `\LaTeX\`  as far as spacing is concerned. As mentioned in the comments there must be something else going on in your example, and for this you need to post a full executable example.

As to what is better: I personally prefer `{}` for the simple reason that allows me to add or remove a punctuation after it without the need to alter it (ie remove `\` ), but that is personal preference. For example, if you used Oxford commas, ie "A, B, C, and D" and then decided to get rid of that, then you can query-replace for ", and" without running into trouble.